# People that are following me can see all the task I open

Tags: chatter

When users browse to my profile they can see all my posts, including information like tasks I opened for other users, which are confidential.

Is there any way to limit this?
How can I restrict users from seeing my chatter activity which I consider confidential?

Comment: I agree totally with @Mike Chale here, I think a better question would be why are you posting confidential information in chatter?  At the very least it should be in a private group.

Answer (score 3):

You can't natively restrict your Chatter activity; everything that you do in Chatter that is not in a private group is automatically public to the entire org.

Ideas:

1. Do your users and stakeholders consider this confidential information? If not, I wouldn't worry about it.
2. If it is confidential, can you reduce or change the information disclosed in the Chatter post so that it doesn't have to be confidential?
3. Is it possible for you to post these updates into a private group, instead?

Comment: Maybe I should have phrased it better - the tasks creation is posted automatically because feed tracking is enabled for tasks. I is really useful for managers to see which tasks their employees have created but I don't want other people (other than the managers) seeing these posts

Comment: Would a report or dashboard be better suited, then?

Comment: We have a report but the concept of Chatter (or wall) really convieniant

Comment: Take a look at chatter publisher actions - http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=actions_overview.htm -- better than turning feed tracking on. You may be able to use profiles, hierarchy, and publishers actions to achieve your goal.